# Laravel: не получается после валидации массива прописать в поля формы старые значения, если данные это ассоциативный массив

Tags: php, массивы, laravel, валидация, форма

Есть документ something.blade.php, где есть форма.
В форме есть 3 поля: `name['az']`, `name['ru']`, `name['en']`.
Я отправляю всё в контроллер и валидирую. Если данные не провалидировались, то меня возвращает на ту же страницу и пишет ошибки. Если это не ассоциативный массив, то пишет все ошибки нормально. А если ассоциативный, то вывести ошибки и старые значения не выходит.

Вот фрагмент кода:

```php
<label for="name['en']"
       class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name EN') }}</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="name['en']" type="text"
           class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name[\'en\']') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
           name="name['en']" value="{{ old('name[\'en\']') }}" autofocus>
    @if ($errors->has('name[\'en\']'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name[\'en\']') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

Как я понимаю, ошибка в том, что я неправильно подаю значения. Если это так, то как правильно подать? А если не так, то в чем дело?

Answer (score 1):

В Laravel есть удобная валидация массивов, [вот документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays).

В вашем случа чтобы провалидировать все 3 поля `name['az']`, `name['ru']`, `name['en']` должен работать этот вариант:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name.*' => 'required|string|unique:users',
]);
```

> Аналогично, вы можете использовать символ * при указании своих
>   сообщений проверки в своих языковых файлах, что делает его легким для
>   использования одного сообщения проверки правильности для полей на
>   основе массива:

```
'custom' => [
    'name.*' => [
        'unique' => 'Каждый пользователь должен иметь уникальное имя',
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный метод таков:

```html
<label for="name['en']"
    class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name EN') }}</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
 <input id="name['en']" type="text"
     class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name.' . '\'en\'') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
     name="name['en']" value="{{ old('name.' . '\'en\'') }}" autofocus>
 @if ($errors->has('name.' . '\'en\''))
  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
  <strong> This field is required </strong>
 </span>
 @endif
</div>
</div>
```